# Django models deifinition many to many field

Tags: django, database-design, django-models, django-admin, many-to-many

I have the following case:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0,validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
```

and in admin.py

```
class ProductsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Order.product.through

class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ProductsInline,]
    filter_horizontal = ('product',)
```

I would like to enter a different quantity for each product while creating one order but with this models it is not possible. Only one quantity per order can be inserted.

I thought of creating an intermediate class ProductQuantity that has a product and its quantity, and then add this to an Order, but i don't know if it is possible to create a ProductQuantity "on the fly" when creating an order.

I can't think of any solution, can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I get your questions. Would this solve your problem?

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(ProductQuantity)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0,validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
```

*Edit:*

With the above Model you could create the following Orders:

```
Products:
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | apple  |
|  2 | orange |
|  3 | banana |
+----+--------+

Order:
+----+-------------+
| id | customer_id |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |         112 |
|  2 |          99 |
+----+-------------+

OrderItem:
+----+-------+---------+----------+
| id | order | product | quantity |
+----+-------+---------+----------+
|  1 |     1 |       1 |       10 |
|  2 |     1 |       2 |       20 |
|  3 |     1 |       3 |       30 |
|  4 |     2 |       1 |        5 |
+----+-------+---------+----------+
```

There are two orders from two different customers, one with 10 apples, 20 oranges and 30 bananas. And a second order with only one item of 5 apples.

Comment: What i want to achieve is that when i create an order i can define the quantity of each product in the order. The quantity defined in the example above is "generic" inside the order. For example i would like to create an order of 10 apples, 20 oranges and 30 bananas.

Comment: @thodoris Then I think I did correctly understand your question. I added an example how such a order would look in the resulting sql tables.

Comment: Ok. But still, if i use the admin to create an Order i would have to go through many steps, first create an order, then create as many OrderItems for that order and this is not very user friendly. What i was thinking was to add OrderItem in Order as a ManyToMany field. But this in the admin interface would link to an already made OrderItem. What i want to achieve is to generate the OrderItem "on the fly". Products already exist but quantities should be introduces when the order is made.

Comment: Defining OrderItems as manytomany doesn't make sense, an OrderItem can only belong to one Order. If you need the maximum usability the Admin Backend is not the right place anyway to create an Order. Make a frontend Mask with a first step creating an Order (specifying the customer) and in the following steps add OrderItems.